# How do I add a flag to an alias?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to add a flag to a *bash* alias you create yourself? e.g.

```
con -a = 'ssh username@server1.domain.com'
con -b = 'ssh username@server2.domain.com'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or, use a function instead of an alias:

```
con() {
  local OPTIND svr
  while getopts ":ab" option; do
    case $option in
      a) svr=server1 ;;
      b) svr=server2 ;;
      ?) echo "invalid option: $OPTARG"; return 1 ;;
    esac
  done
  ssh username@${svr}.domain.com
}

con -a
```

Comment: Right. Though, considering OP only needs a single flag, the `getopts` loop might be a teensy-weensy bit overkill :).

Comment: If you're going to show someone how to do something, show them the correct way.

Comment: not contesting the merits of your answer – I linked to it indicating it is better than mine.

Comment: Can this be placed in .profile along with aliases?

Comment: .bashrc is usually recommended

Answer (score 2):

Nope – aliases are simple text substitutions. Use different alias names instead:

```
alias cona='ssh username@server1.domain.com' 
alias conb='ssh username@server2.domain.com'
```

*EDIT if absolutely must have flags, a function will serve better than an alias – [see @glenn-jackmann’s answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51010/11948)*.